# Can Ruby 1.9.1 finally get a list of filenames if the filenames have unicode characters on Windows?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

Can Ruby 1.9.1 finally get a list of filenames if the filenames have unicode characters on Windows?

I think back in the Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 days, that wasn't possible on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.2/YARV 1.9.2 has massively improved non-ASCII filename support on Windows. You can read all about it in bug [*#1685: Some windows unicode path issues remain*](http://RedMine.Ruby-Lang.Org/issues/show/1685/).

However, it is still possible that it will work for you on 1.9.1 if you don't hit any of the bugs.

Comment: i know somebody was using ``cmd /U /C dir /B`` to simulate it on Windows... but Ruby 1.8.7 behaves better with it.  Ruby 1.9.1 changes 0x0a to 0x0d and messed up the UTF-16